# SQL Server Delete rows when timestamp is older than 1 month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete rows when timestamp is older than 1 month in SQL Server.

What I got so far is:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE DATEDIFF(month,getdate(),myColumn) < -1
```

This is not deleting anything from my table although it should. What is wrong with this query/is there a better way of writing this query?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The query looks ok, but realize that DATEDIFF rounds the result, so only records that are 2+ months in the past will return a number < -1 (you can change it to <= -1 to fix that part).

Comment: Also, if it's not deleting what you think it should, change the DELETE to a SELECT * and run the query manually to see what records it is or isn't matching.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rounding issues with the month function may give you issues - you'd probably be better off with a DATEADD() instead, e.g.,

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE MyColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, myColumn, GETDATE()) >=30
```